# I want Radio button widget and text widget inline

Tags: flutter

I want the single selected radio button widget and text widget in the same row. It won't work even if I try to wrap it with the row. I want it like the image below.[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3whid.jpg), [But I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuyAw.jpg). Thanks in advance!

```
Column(
            children: [
              RadioListTile(
                title: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ///use your image
                      Text(
                        "  English",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff000000),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                value: "English",
                groupValue: "english",
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                tileColor: Color(0xff28e8df),
              ),
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffbebdbd),
                      border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffbebdbd)),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text("العربية",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              color: Color(0xff000000),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Row` widget and **wrap** each child in it with `Expanded`, because `RadioListTile` want to take the width of its parent, and `Row` wait its children to render, so it can know its own width.

By using `Expanded` the `Row` know that it must take all the possible with, and it's children can fit correctly in it.

Answer (score 0):

try this update i hope it will fix the issue

```
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                height: 50,
                child: RadioListTile(
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ///use your image
                        Text(
                          "  English",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff000000),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  value: "English",
                  groupValue: "english",
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  tileColor: Color(0xff28e8df),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffbebdbd),
                  border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffbebdbd)),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "العربية",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```